# Error in Laravel Artisan command

Tags: php, laravel-artisan, laravel-5.3

I am new in Laravel. I am using Laravel 5.3.I used below code to install Laravel 5.3.

php composer.phar create-project laravel/laravel=5.3 addbook dev-develop

I tried to executed "php artsisan --v" but I found below error

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ErrorException: array_merge(): Argument #1 is not an
array in D:\php7\htdocs\addbook\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundati
on\Exceptions\Handler.php:93

Stack trace:

#0 [internal function]: Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->handle
Error(2, 'array_merge(): ...', 'D:\\php7\\htdocs\\...', 93, Array)

#1 D:\php7\htdocs\addbook\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Exc
eptions\Handler.php(93): array_merge(Array)

#2 D:\php7\htdocs\addbook\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Exc
eptions\Handler.php(61): Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler->shouldntRepor
t(Object(ErrorException))

#3 D:\php7\htdocs\addbook\app\Exceptions\Handler.php(35): Illuminate\Foundation\
Exceptions\Handler->report(Object(ErrorException))

#4 D:\php7\htdocs\addbook\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Boo
tstrap\HandleExceptions.php(79): App\Exceptions\Handler->report(Object(ErrorExce
ption))

#5 [internal function]: Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->handle
Exce in D:\php7\htdocs\addbook\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundatio
n\Exceptions\Handler.php on line 93
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ErrorException: array_merge(): Argument #1 is not an
array in D:\php7\htdocs\addbook\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundati
on\Exceptions\Handler.php:93

Stack trace:

#0 [internal function]: Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->handle
Error(2, 'array_merge(): ...', 'D:\\php7\\htdocs\\...', 93, Array)
#1 D:\php7\htdocs\addbook\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Exc
eptions\Handler.php(93): array_merge(Array)
#2 D:\php7\htdocs\addbook\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Exc
eptions\Handler.php(61): Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler->shouldntRepor
t(Object(Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException))
#3 D:\php7\htdocs\addbook\app\Exceptions\Handler.php(35): Illuminate\Foundation\
Exceptions\Handler->report(Object(Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorEx
ception))
#4 D:\php7\htdocs\addbook\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Boo
tstrap\HandleExceptions.php(79): App\Exceptions\Handler->report(Object(Symfony\C
omponent\Debug in D:\php7\htdocs\addbook\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate
\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler.php on line 93
```

Can anyone say what is the solution ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, don't use the develop branch!

Run `php composer.phar create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel=5.3 addbook`.

---

Also, if your Composer Vendor folder is your path, you should be able to achieve the same by running
`laravel new addbook`

Answer (score 0):

You need pull stability version, try add param --prefer-dist

`composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel addbook`